# sharing cart multistore magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, multistore

I have 4 store with different domain name. and I want to share cart for 4 stores I have research and implement this url :

**http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html**

but it doesn't work. `cart still separate. anyone has experience on sharing on Magento 1.9.1` .

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that now you simply have to set `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options > Share Customer Accounts` = **Global**.

There is also some session modifications that need to be done, see here: http://astrio.net/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores/

Comment: I think this's only share customer account. but cart is not sharing. am i wrong ?

Comment: Yeah my bad I updated my answer

Comment: thanks but I also tried this website, it not working as well